# Symfony2 editing PDF

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, fpdi

I have a problem when trying to edit existing PDF. In non-symfony part of code I've used FPDI library and I could just open existing pdf as:

```
$pdf->setSourceFile('example.pdf');
```

Now in the symfony part of the project we're using White october bundle for symfony2 which is basically wrapper around TCPDF library.

But the problem is TCPDF does not have any option to open existing file as template. So is there any way I could edit existing pdf file without including another bundle? Since I don't want to have multiple bundles doing almost exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of TCPDF library, you can use [the import method](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF__IMPORT.html).

If your library doesn't allow it, [use another one ?](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle)

Edit: [KnpSnappy doesn't allow editing](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/173). Only generating.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with Snappy Bundle, but I'm not quite sure that I can load PDF and edit it. If it can, can you please link that documentation since I can't find it in their documentation

Comment: My bad. Snappy doesn't allow it. It doesn't take long to create a html file though.

Comment: Well, the problem is I can't create HTML file like that since is some custom template (and it's done by external associate), and can't make html like that one.

Comment: Then, look through the import method and fingers crossed it'd look the same.

Comment: Well when you try to TCPDF import file, it does absolutely nothing, or I don't know how to use it. Tried $tcpdf->import(filename); but nah, getting empty file

Comment: [Try asking on the official support forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311) or find someone asking the same thing. Good luck.